# Custom transition from a VC to another VC inside a view

Tags: ios, swift

I have this code that changes a VC to another VC inside a view (containerView). The code works, but how do i set a transition between both views?

```
var childVC: UIViewController?
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: UIView!

func ChangeViewController() { 
    childVC?.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    childVC?.view.removeFromSuperview()
    childVC?.removeFromParentViewController()
    childVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("identifier") as? UIViewController
    if let childVC = childVC {
        addChildViewController(childVC)
        childVC.view.frame = containerView.bounds 
        containerView.addSubview(childVC.view)
        childVC.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    }
}
```

I tried, but didnt work:

```
let oldView = childVC?.view
UIView.transitionFromView(oldView!, toView: childVC.view, duration: 2, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromLeft, completion: { (succeed) -> Void in

        })
```

Answer (score 0):

To transition between VCs, you can display each VC in a view and animate them in and out of view in the container view. Something along these lines:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self.containerView];

// Your animations here

[UIView commitAnimations];
```